# Do the terms multi-task and multi-output refer to the same thing in the context of deep learning?

Tags: neural-networks, comparison, terminology, multi-label-classification, multi-task-learning

Do the terms multi-task and multi-output refer to the same thing in the context of deep learning (with neural networks)? For example, do neural networks for multi-task learning use multiple outputs?

If **not**, what is the difference between them?

It would be helpful if you can also give examples.

I found some of the terms [here](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/28639/how-can-i-approach-this-problem/28643#28643). When I went to study this term on the Internet, I found it very convoluted, as different authors are found to be mixing up those terms.